# Hot water heater T&P discharge going into furnace condensate pump?

Tags: plumbing, furnace, water-heater, drain

I recently had some electrical work done at my house, and as part of that, the power was shut off. After a few minutes, we noticed water coming from the closet containing the hot water heater and furnace. There was a slow and steady trickle of water coming out of the condensate pump, and we could feel the heat in the discharge line connecting the pump to the t&p valve.

The next day, I talked to two different plumbers about this. One said that line should be going to a drain, but there's no drain in my basement. The other said it was ok for that line to be connected to the pump, but there should be a shut-off valve on the hot water side of the heater.

Who (if any) is right? I'm most interested in what would be considered up to code in Pennsylvania. Since that's a vague question, I'll also ask a specific one: what's the best thing for me to do to ensure the next time I lose power, my basement doesn't slowly flood?

**Edit**: because a picture is worth a thousand words.

[image: water heater and furnace]

Comment: What make and model is your condensate pump?  I somehow doubt it's rated for what a T&P valve will discharge when it's busy preventing your water heater from putting a hole in your roof....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: it's [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Little-Giant-VCL-24ULS-115-Volt-Condensate-Removal-Pump-553201/204481233); there's a spec sheet on that page too (though I don't know what I'm looking for).

Comment: I need to ruminate on this for a while -- you're in a real sticky wicket, since I suspect your pump is representative in topping out at 120degF inlet water, and could be damaged by the 180+degF water coming out of a T&P that's doing its job...

Comment: i9n normal; usage the flow from that valve will be very slow an should cool sufficiently before it reaches the pump, if the thermostat fails there's going to be a mess no matter what you do.

Comment: easiest fix is probably battery backup for the pump. increasing the condensate sump volume is probably a better fix but more complicated.

Comment: @Jasen: What do you think about the second plumber's suggestion to add a shut-off valve on the hot water line to the heater? Could that possibly help in this situation?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Thanks for ruminating! Here is an easier question (I think): is this wicket sticky enough that I could use it to convince my wife we should get a tankless heater? :)

Comment: when the water heats up it expands, a shut-off valve could limit the amount of leakage duting a prolonged power cut and leave you without hot water until it was reopened

Comment: I don't like the idea of just slapping in a tankless, as a unit replacment for a tanked heater; that just leads to a more quirky heater.  A tankless *deserves* the benefit of more careful system design, so it lives up to its impressive potential (not least, being able to be installled in many more choices of location). So I would start thinking hard about that... *real fast*... Meanwhile see if just swapping the T&P will get you by...

Comment: @Harper: thanks for the info. Do you have any pointers to coming up with a more careful design?

Answer (score 1):

If the T&P relief valve opens for most reason it is designed for, (over pressure or over temperature) the  water flow can be a slow trickle or could be a fast and sometimes violent event. If it is a slow trickle, the pump will handle the water but if it a quick discharge there is going to be a lot of water flow. As far as the valve on the hot water side of the heater, I have no idea how that will alleviate any of your problems, unless i do not understand it's function. Without a drain in the basement, I would not store anything in that area that could be harmed by water. If the water heater's T&P valve is flowing a small amount of water you need to find out why this is happening. If it leaks all the time you may need a PRV to limit the water pressure in the house or the T&P valve may be worn out and need to be replaced, and if happens only when you use hot water and the water is being reheated , you may need to have an  expansion tank installed to accept the expanded water as it is being reheated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you think the best option here is?

Comment: Carefully re-read my answer and determine when the water is flowing from the T&P valve. That will determine what your need is. However, if you do not have an expansion tank on your hot water tank, that is the first item I would add, it is a code requirement where I live. You could buy a pressure gauge that screws onto a faucet with threads to check the standing water house pressure. My pressure is  usually around 75 PSIG. And If the existing T&P valve is 10 years or older I would replace it.

Comment: Thanks again. I had a plumber already install the shut-off valve and a new T&P valve. I'm going to have an HVAC specialist come out and talk me through adding an expansion tank and battery backup for pump.